# Separating Variables for Forced Inhomogeneous Wave Equation on a Close and Bounded Domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having some issues applying separation of variables to the following PDE:

$u_{tt}= \nabla \cdot (A \nabla u) + gsin\omega t\\u(x,0)=\phi(x)\\u_t(x,0)=\Psi(x)\\u|_{\delta D}=0$

where D is a closed and bounded domain with a smooth boundary, $g, \psi(x), \Psi(x)$ are $H_{0}^{1}$ functions, $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, and $A:D \to \mathbb{R}^{dxd}$ is a smooth, symmetric matrix valued function.

I am having issues separating the variables when I assume the solution is of the form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$.

Comment: Even if you can separate variables--and there is no guarantee--then the boundary conditions can't be applied unless the boundary is a constant coordinate surface.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Homogeneous separation of variables conditions require that the surfaces where you specify the $0$ condition translate to $X(a)$ or $Y(a)$, etc., which means that the surface components must be rectangular in the variables used to separate variables. How else can you specify a condition on $X_1(x_1)X_2(x_2)X_3(x_3)\cdots$ unless the surface translates to $x_1 = a$ and $a_2 \le x_2 \le b_2$, $a_3 \le x_3 \le b_3,\cdots$ or some such condition in another variable? That's the standard requirement for separation of variables: the homogeneous conditions become endpoint conditions for an ODE.